# Is there a difference between terminal update and software center update in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I'm updating my system through `sudo dnf update` command, but sometimes there is a notification that there are new updates available but I can see them only in software center neither `sudo dnf update --refresh` won't show any new updates. So I was just wondering what is the difference between that and what should I prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both use the same back end dependency solver and pull from the same repositories, but due to different projects moving a different speeds, they don't pull from a unified local cache (including the metadata cache — the information about what updates are available and so on). And, because Fedora distributes content on a large volunteer mirror network, sometimes that's not all in sync — that's probably why `dnf --refresh` isn't doing any good.

The longer-term plan is for this to converge, avoiding the duplication.

As for which to prefer, the main difference is whether the updates are done online or offline — and offline requires a reboot. That's obviously usually less convenient, but it ensures that all security patches are actually in effect, and avoids glitches like [Flash plugin up to date but Firefox keeps telling me that I have the old version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174210/flash-plugin-up-to-date-but-firefox-keeps-telling-me-that-i-have-the-old-version) (and potentially more serious problems with the system on disk being out of sync with what's running).